# Manipular Date no ASP.NET

Tags: c#

Estou começando a aprender ASP.NET e não consigo achar solução para o caso abaixo:

Tenho uma instância do DateTime onde eu faço a conversão para o formato "ddMMyyyy" usando o ParseExact(), pra mostrar a data sem máscara. O problema é que no Oracle esse campo não é DATETIME, é só DATE. Quando rodo o programa, recebo o erro `"A cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como valor DateTime válido."`

Não encontrei nenhum objeto só do tipo Date no ASP.NET pra usar. Alguem tem ideia de como posso resolver isso? Não queria ter que alterar o tipo do campo na tabela.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
else if (field.TYPECODE == 4)
                        {
                            DateTime _date = DateTime.ParseExact(field.VALUE, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                            field.VALUE = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_date);
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

O que está acontecendo é que você inicialmente tem essa data em string, provavelmente recebida por input, porém por algum motivo você precisa trabalhar com ela deserializada em DateTime, para isso você está dando parse.

O problema está exatamente aí, a api do ParseExact pede para você o valor a ser parseado, porém ele precisa saber como fazer isso para que possa trabalhar, no caso o formato.

Para que o parse ocorra, o formato que a data em string esta tem que corresponder exatamente com o do formato informado, senão ele não vai conseguir realizar, pois não saberá o formato correto e como trabalhar.

Quando isso acontece, ele lança uma exceção com a seguinte característica:

> FormatException: s does not contain a date and time that corresponds to the pattern specified in format.

Vamos para um exemplo errado e correto:

Errado:

```
    ...
    field.VALUE = "10/10/2020";
    var _date = DateTime.ParseExact(field.VALUE, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Ira falhar, pois o formatado da data não ira corresponder a informada para ele parsear.

-

Certo:

```
    ...
    field.VALUE = "10102020";
    var _date = DateTime.ParseExact(field.VALUE, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Ira retornar a data serializada em DateTime, pois o formatado da data corresponde
com o formato informado para ele parsear.

Então o seu problema esta na diferença do formato da data recebida com o qual você quer que o parser utilize para deserializar.

Para aprofundamento sobre a api do mesmo, acesse a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_).

Abraços.